# Using acquaintance for admission in Ph.D

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I am a Ph.D. student at an institute in maths department. This year my brother also has applied for Ph.D. in the same institute in Civil engineering department. Now he has to face a written test first to get qualified for the interview. The syllabus of test is given on the website but no information about exam styles or paper pattern is provided. My brother has told me to ask the professors about the paper pattern. Personally I do not think it is a good idea because this way my brother will get advantage over others and I am also worried about my impression on the professors. So should I ask my professorship this? If not how should I convince my brother that it's not proper way?

Answer (score 1):

I can't judge but it is possible that the question you want to ask might be open to anyone, including your brother, to ask directly. It depends on whether the format of the exam is intentionally held secret, which seems possible but implausible.

You could first ask your advisor whether it is *proper* to ask about the format. If you get a *yes*, then ask, or tell your brother to ask.

Some questions that could be asked simply aren't for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It is not improper to ask for information.  Your brother does not gain an advantage by asking for information, either with a direct or indirect request.  Any applicant can ask for information.

It is up to the department that has the information to decide if it is proper to grant the request.

Comment: Except he did not ask the department. He asked relative in the department who is not on interview panel and who clearly has a conflict of interests.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov That's not true.  The asker is a PhD student who is not in the civil engineering department.  There is no conflict of interest for the asker because the asker's only interest is in helping the brother.  The asker, as a PhD student, has no interest in the proper testing of PhD students.